# What are the eigenvalues of a particular type of block partitioned matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, block-matrices, characteristic-polynomial

Let $C=\begin{bmatrix} A & \pm J \\ \pm J^T & B\end{bmatrix}$ be a square block partitioned matrix of order $m+n$ where $A$ and $B$ are square symmetric matrices of orders $m$ and $n$ respectively with entries from the set $\{-1,0,1\}$ such that the diagonal entries of $A$ and $B$ are always zero and $J$ is a matrix of all ones. Can anyone suggest method to find the characteristic polynomial and eigenvalues of $C$ in terms of the corresponding facts of $A$ and $B$ ( and if required that of $J$ also) ?

Comment: Looks like the incidence matrix for directed graph.

Comment: @Awe Kumar Jha It is not related with the incidence matrix of a graph. But with the adjacency matrices $A$ and $B$ of two graphs

Answer (score 0):

For the case where both plus signs occur in $C$:

Shur's formula when $\lambda$ is not an eigenvalue of $A$ gives
$$
 {\rm det\,}\begin{bmatrix} A-\lambda I & J \cr
                            J         & B-\lambda I 
             \end{bmatrix}
 =
 {\rm det\,}(A-\lambda I){\rm det\,}(-J(A-\lambda I)^{-1}J+B-\lambda I).
$$
For any matrix $M$ you have that $JMJ = kJ$ where $k$ is the sum of
all elements of $M$. Therefore
$$
 {\rm det\,}C = {\rm det\,}(A-\lambda I){\rm det\,}(B-a(\lambda)J-\lambda I),
$$
where $a(\lambda)$ is the sum of all elements of $(A-\lambda I)^{-1}$.